# Redirect class breaking terminal - testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to run test using Jest and Ezyme

Editworkflow is one of the state, and it is redirecting to another location.
If i set it = true, it breaks the terminal.

I was able to do the following after some research

```
describe("when user has permission", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper.setState({editWorkflow: true, selectedWorkId:true });
  wrapper.instance().history.replace('/add'); // replace the MemoryRouter location with 
  wrapper.update(); // update the wrapper with the changes
  })

it("Test click event on Workflows - Cancel/AddWork", () => {
  baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
  expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Redirect to="/add" />)).toEqual(true)
  expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Redirect to="/edit/" />)).toEqual(true)
  wrapper.find('Workflows').find('#add-work-button').at(0).simulate("click");
  wrapper.find('Workflows').find('#add-work-button').at(1).simulate("click");
  );
```

At the moment the terminal is not breaking, but the test is not passing either.

Here is the error:

```
 expect(received).toEqual(expected)

 Expected value to equal:
   true
 Received:
   false

 expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Redirect to="/add"/>)).toEqual(true)
```

If i set the statement above equals to False, the terminal breaks again

Here is where the state is calling Redirect

```
{ this.state.editWorkflow ? <Redirect push to={`${this.props.location.pathname}/add`} /> : null }
{ this.state.selectedWorkId ? <Redirect push to={`${this.props.location.pathname}/edit/${this.state.selectedWorkId}`} /> : null }
```

How could I write the following test and prevent this to happen, using Jest and Enzyme

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting?

Comment: npm ERR! Test failed. thats all.

Comment: @CameronDowner i made a few adjustments in my test. I am able to run the file and terminal doesn't break, the other tests and click events are going through. This one is failing due to this reason

Comment: expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      true
    Received:
      false

Comment: When i make it equal to false : terminal breaks

Comment: I'm a bit lost in your question.  I'm finding it hard to see what you are trying to achieve past getting a test to pass. Could you have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a simple, repeatable problem?

Comment: I will edit make quesiton ,

Comment: @CameronDowner is it better now ?